# What principles of physics makes a Shkadov Thruster produce thrust?

Tags: astrophysics

I don't understand the principles at play that make a [Shkadov Thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_engine) produce thrust upon a star. As I understand the idea, you produce a mega structure on one side of a star, reflecting half of its light back in the direction of the other light produced from the star. Somehow this produces a thrust for the star in the direction of the mirror.

But how does that light produce thrust for the star? If I face a wall and throw a tennis ball at it and the ball bounces back toward me over my head, does that bounce and redirection of the tennis ball somehow propel me toward the wall? I don't think so. If not, how does the reflection of the star's photons in the other direction from the mirror produce thrust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mirror megastructure acts as a light sail, the radiation from the star acts to push the light sail away. The light sail is not orbiting the star, so gravity will pull them together. With the gravitational attraction equal to the radiational thrust on the mirror they will maintain the same distance from each other. Thus the mirror's gravity is dragging the star along with it as the star's radiation accelerates the mirror.

Comment: Ah OK. So just to make sure I understand this right: the radiation pressure from the sun captured by the sale, the weight of the sale, and the thrust upon the sun, are all the same. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, everything would be kept in balance so the star would fall towards the sail as the sail was pushed by radiation.

Answer (score 1):

What if you and the wall are floating in space but you are tethered to the wall? The tether will pull you towards the rebounding wall (both moving away from the ball).

The mirror structure is tethered to the star by gravity, so the radiation pressure pushes it away from the star, and it drags the star along.